# Typescript 1.8.5, VueJS 1.0.28 and VS2013

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I need a way or DefinitelyTyped interfaces for VueJS (v1.0.28)

In more simple words, the project need pure typescript separated files, and now we using Javascript into  tags.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/types check this

Comment: This is for Vue2!